# Filter date from last 3 months to next 3 months

Tags: tableau-api

In a date filter in Tableau it is possible to select 'last 3 months', 'next 3 months', etc. But I can't find a way to show the last 3 months, the current month and the next three months together - relative to Today.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can create a set with condition something like abs(month(date)-month(today())<4

Comment: Works perfectly, just added AND year(date) = year(today()). Thanks so much!

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot about the year part completly